# Python submodule import error (Google App Engine dev_appserver.py)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, virtualenv, dev-appserver

I have the following code in `appengine_config.py`:

```
...
import six
print six.__version__
print six.moves
import six.moves
```

The output is as follows:

```
1.11.0
<module 'six.moves' (built-in)>
ERROR    2018-04-17 10:51:19,875 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 351, in __get
attr__
    self._update_configs()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 287, in _update_configs
    self._registry.initialize()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 160, in initi
alize
    import_func(self._modname)
  File "/home/user/project/appengine_config.py", line 17, in <module>
    from six.moves import http_client
ImportError: No module named moves
```

How is it possible that `moves` is a module when accessed through `six`, but can't be imported on its own?

To give some context about the environment:

- I use a clean Debian GCE VM.
- Install python 2.7, virtualenv, from within virtualenv install a short list of basic dependencies.
- The script is run from within dev_appserver.py (Google App Engine standard environment local dev server)
- `six.moves` imports fine from python shell

Comment: Ok, the problem was with libraries in `app.yaml`. After removing all dependencies from there, everything worked.

Comment: could you post this as answer and provide a bit more details on what was failing? Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51616840/901444

Answer (score 0):

You've already imported `six`.  That includes `six.moves`.  So just use it as `six.moves`.  To import just moves, use:

```
from six import moves
```

Comment: Well, the actual problematic line is `from six.moves import http_client` and I don't have control over that line.

Comment: That's not what the error says.  It says from line `import six.moves
ImportError: No module named moves`

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in the problem statement. I described the debug lines I have that cause the same behavior, but not the original problem. I will edit the question now.